# Update table records if values match records value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, match, record

I have two tables

```
Table1

Date       Number      Name      Memo          PaidAmount
2012-02-13 122361      John Doe  some memo     245.25
2014-06-29 146352      Steve Doe another memo  360.34


Table2

Date       FileNumber  Name      Address       Price     Status
2012-02-13 122361PH    John Doe  some memo     245.25    Pending
2014-06-29 146352AP    Steve Doe another memo  360.34    Pending
```

I need to update records' Status in "Table2" from Pending to Closed only in records which FileNumbers' first six digits match first six digits of "Number" in "Table1".

And here is what's in my head...

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Status = Closed
Where Table2.FileNumber (first six digits) = Table1.Number (first six digits)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table2 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON substr( Table2.number, 1, 6 ) = substr( Table1.number, 1, 6 )
SET STATUS = 'Closed'
```

Comment: LaFabriqueDeCode: when I used your code, it changed all FileNumber first four digits values in Table2 to like 14000. Also updated only two Status to "Closed" when there are like over 2000 records that should have updtated.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it.

```
    update 
    Table2
    inner join
    Table1 on SUBSTRING(Table1.Number,1,6) = SUBSTRING(Table2.FileNumber,1,6)
    SET Table2.Status = 'Closed'
```

Comment: Abnik, I tried using your code, but I get an error: ERROR 1064 (24000): You have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET Table2.Status = 'Closed'' at line 6

Comment: pardon me I have a typo set was there 2 times, I have corrected it.